# How JSON Web Tokens work? Not sure what is different from cookies

Tags: security, cookies, authentication, token, jwt

When using cookies they are stored on the server and compared to the ones coming in the request from a client. What are the JWTs compared to? are they being decoded into their components?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do we need JWT when we have client sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997520/why-do-we-need-jwt-when-we-have-client-sessions)

Comment: No, this is a completely different question

Comment: Yes, on further consideration they are different (there are similarities, but yours is focused on the "how" not the "why"). I will answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *JSON Web Signature* (JWS) JWT is not "compared to" anything; rather it is *validated* using a cryptographic key.  [Various algorithms](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-algorithms-40#section-3) are supported.  The system validating the JWT must have access to the appropriate key for validating a particular JWT.

For *symmetric* algorithms (`HS{256,384,512}`) the JWS object comprising the token is validated using the HMAC construction with the SHA-2 cryptographic digest, keyed by a *shared secret*, i.e. the same key used to produce the token must be used to validate it.

For *asymmetric* algorithms (`{RS,ES,PS}{256,384,512}`) the JWS object comprising the token is validated using the RSASSA-PKCSv1.5 (`RS`), ECDSA (`ES`) or RSASSA-PSS (`PS`) algorithms with the SHA-2 cryptographic digest, using the *public key* corresponding to the *private key* used to sign the JWS.

The process of validating a JWS (a JWT is always serialized using the *JWS compact serialization*) is defined in the [JWS Internet-Draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature-41#section-5.2).  In brief, the token is split into its three parts: header (a base64-encoded JSON object), payload (base64-encoded octet string; for JWT this is a JSON *JWT claims* object) and signature (base64-encoded octet string).  The header indentifies the algorithm used, and this algorithm is used to verify the signature, which is computed across `ASCII(BASE64URL(UTF8(Header)) || '.' ||  BASE64URL(Payload))` (this *signing input* is exactly the serialised JWT up to but not including the second period.)